# How can I sort list of object based on one of the object's variables

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

I need to sort an ArrayList of films best rated to worse (5 best - 1 worst). I am using Collections.sort() but the list comes out the same. what am i doing wrong

```
films.add(new Film().setRating(1));
films.add(new Film().setRating(2.5));
films.add(new Film().setRating(3.5));
films.add(new Film().setRating(4));
films.add(new Film().setRating(5));
films.add(new Film().setRating(1));
films.add(new Film().setRating(2));
films.add(new Film().setRating(3));
films.add(new Film().setRating(4));
Collections.sort(films, new Comparator<Film>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Film o1, Film o2) {
        final double film1 = o1.getRating();
        final double film2 = o2.getRating();
        return film1 > film2? 1
                : film1 < film2? -1 : 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: side note: you really need double precision to hold ratings?

Comment: What is the concrete class for films?  

"Comparators can also be used to control the order of certain data structures (such as sorted sets or sorted maps)"

Comment: @dantuch probably not

Comment: @WaleryStrauch There's no reason whatsoever that should make a difference if the code compiles.

Comment: @user521180: Using the obvious implementation of `Film`, I can find nothing wrong with your code: http://ideone.com/m7tHJg The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Your code works just fine on my computer..

Comment: Everything looks fine. The problem must be inside the `Film` class. See, that's why people invented SSCCEs :) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `Double.compare` method works fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    final List<Film> films = new ArrayList<>();
    films.add(new Film().setRating(1));
    films.add(new Film().setRating(2.5));
    films.add(new Film().setRating(3.5));
    films.add(new Film().setRating(4));
    films.add(new Film().setRating(5));
    films.add(new Film().setRating(1));
    films.add(new Film().setRating(2));
    films.add(new Film().setRating(3));
    films.add(new Film().setRating(4));
    System.out.println(films);
    Collections.sort(films, new Comparator<Film>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Film o1, Film o2) {
            return Double.compare(o1.getRating(), o2.getRating());
        }
    });
    System.out.println(films);
}
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 2.5, 3.5, 4.0, 5.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

The `Film` I used:

```
private static final class Film {

    double rating;

    public double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public Film setRating(double rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Double.toString(rating);
    }
}
```

I would suggest using `Double.compare` rather than your version, or even `o1.getRating - o2.getRating`.

It's either that or your `Film` implementation is wrong - maybe the setter in your example doesn't set anything?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the OP's comparison. (Why would it be? Surely `<` and `>` works for `doubles` in Java. `=` might be flaky because of epsilon issues but that wouldn't cause the behaviour the OP is seeing.) Your answer changes (and thus fixes) nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Use the folowing method in `Double` instead:

```
public static int compare(double d1, double d2){}
```

or like this:

```
class Film implements Comparable<Film>{
    double rating;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Film o) {
        return Double.compare(rating, o.rating);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I then use that method?

Comment: Collections.sort(films) is OK

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine on my computer, the following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;


public class SortFilms {
    public static void main(final String ... args) {
        new SortFilms().sort();
    }

    public void sort() {
        final List<Film> films = new ArrayList<Film>();
        films.add(new Film(1));
        films.add(new Film(2.5));
        films.add(new Film(3.5));
        films.add(new Film(4));
        films.add(new Film(5));
        films.add(new Film(1));
        films.add(new Film(2));
        films.add(new Film(3));
        films.add(new Film(4));
        Collections.sort(films, new Comparator<Film>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Film o1, Film o2) {
                final double film1 = o1.getRating();
                final double film2 = o2.getRating();
                return film1 > film2? 1
                        : film1 < film2? -1 : 0;
            }
        });

        System.out.println(films);
    }

    private class Film {
        private final double rating;

        public Film(double rating) {
            this.rating = rating;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "" + rating;
        }

        public Double getRating() {
            return rating;
        }
    }
}
```

Procudes:

```
[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of solving this problem

1. Implementing compare method of comparator interface in second parameter of Collections.sort method.
2. Ensuring your class implements Comparable interface and then implementing compareTo method.

Here is the code for both solutions.

```js
public class ComparableTest implements Comparable < ComparableTest > {

  String name;
  int marks;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(ComparableTest o) {
    if (this.marks > o.marks)
      return 1;
    return -1;
  }

  public ComparableTest(String name, int marks) {
    this.name = name;
    this.marks = marks;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public int getMarks() {
    return marks;
  }

}
```

```js
package program;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class TempList {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*************************************************/
    /****************Assigning Values*****************/
    /*************************************************/
    String[] names = {
      "A",
      "B",
      "C",
      "D",
      "E"
    };
    List < ComparableTest > objects = new LinkedList < > ();

    /*************************************************/
    /****************Printing Values******************/
    /*************************************************/

    for (String name: names) {
      objects.add(new ComparableTest(name, new Random().nextInt(100)));
    }

    System.out.println("Before Sorting");

    for (ComparableTest object: objects) {
      System.out.println(object.name + " " + object.marks);
    }

    /*************************************************/
    /*************Sorting based on marks**************/
    /*************************************************/

    Collections.sort(objects);
    System.out.println("\nSorting based on Marks");

    for (ComparableTest object: objects) {
      System.out.println(object.name + " " + object.marks);
    }

    /*************************************************/
    /*************Sorting based on names**************/
    /*************************************************/

    System.out.println("\nSorting based on Names");

    Collections.sort(objects, new Comparator < ComparableTest > () {

      @Override
      public int compare(ComparableTest o1, ComparableTest o2) {
        if (o1.name.compareTo(o2.name) < 1) {
          return 1;
        }
        return -1;
      }

    });

    for (ComparableTest object: objects) {
      System.out.println(object.name + " " + object.marks);
    }
  }

}
```